# Single word for "I take no pleasure in this" or "I know this seems over the top, but it must be done"

Tags: single-word-requests

Something that looks outwardly evil or self-serving, but is genuinely being done for moral and unselfish reasons.

As an example, a civil war surgeon is sawing off the arm of a screaming man to save his life from his infected wounds. A young boy is watching this and does not comprehend what is happening, and understandably thinks the man is being horrifically tortured. In this scenario my omniscient narrator would say: "The boy did not understand the _______ act he was seeing."

As in, this seemingly sadistic evil act, that is in reality entirely necessary and even virtuous.

Comment: *necessary* or better yet *necessity of*

Comment: This sounds like "for the greater good", but that is not a single word.

Comment: Maybe you can say "regretably."

Answer (score 1):

I presume you've already rejected **necessary evil** (which isn't a single word), although that does fit the bill nicely.

How about **expedient**?

> helpful or useful in a particular situation, but sometimes not morally acceptable

*It might be expedient not to pay him until the work is finished.*

*The management has taken a series of expedient measures to improve the company's financial situation.*

[Cambridge]

Comment: Necessary evil is certainly the closest, but I have this feeling that there is a word I've used before that fits better. Because in the case of the civil war surgeon it isn't a necessary "evil" at all, and rather just the unfortunate reality of surgery in a pre-anesthetic world. The word I'm looking for is more about the observer and the misunderstanding. The observer is not confused or conflicted at all. They are seeing a man screaming in pain and tortured for no apparent reason, and they are SURE it is evil. But it is a tragic misunderstanding, being described by an omniscient narrator

Comment: In other words you're trying to blend together the two aspects of the situation: the grossness of it (as viewed by the observer) and the reality (as known to the doctor and the omniscient narrator). I doubt if a single word could cover both these aspects. It's grotesque for the observer, but necessary in the eyes of the doctor.

Comment: Yeah I think that's a fair summation. But I still have it in my head that there is a single word for this. Something similar to the way "anachronistic" is sometimes used -- where something is very clearly out of it's place in time to the reader/narrator, but not necessarily to the "observer". But in my specific case I want something being obviously moral/ethical to the reader/narrator, but not necessarily to the "observer".

If there is no single word for that, I guess I'm looking for a short pointed phrase communicating the same idea.